# React how to test popup

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme, jestjs

I have button. When I click button the popup will appear. But popup appears in delay. So the problem is that I cannot use code like this

```
wrapper.find(button).simulate('click')
expect(modal.exists()).to.be.true;
```

this code only works if I add setTimeout

Is there some elegant way to handle this?

Comment: The modal showing should be triggered by a change in state from, say `false` to `true`. So I think you want to that on click of button something is dispatched/state changes.

Comment: You mean that I should check state instead of checking if modal rendered?

Comment: Yes. You have to trust that state does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, completed, reproducible code.